# How pycharm extract variable like .var+tab in idea, without using CTRL+ALT+V?

Tags: pycharm

1. Intellij Idea can extract variable with .var+tab. such as:
   new ArrayList().var + enter, and then, i get:
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
2. but in pycharm i can not do like that, who can tell me how to  extract variable with .var+tab. in pycharm.
3. ps: i have search in google, finding the keyword of the problem is 'Postfix Completion', thus, i have found the pligin in https://plugins.jetbrains.com/, and get the plugin 'Custom Postfix Templates', but i can not use it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Postfix Completion` and tick in the box at the top `Enable postfix completion`.

In the box below it you can to choose which key to use to this purpose (Tab, Space, or Enter)